# Cross-Validation vs. AICc for LASSO

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, lasso, aic

I was working on a research project in which I try to estimate the the individual contribution of a group of regional political leaders to local economic growth. The major challenge is that there is relatively few locality-year observations to the number of regional leaders. Overall I have about 300 political leaders and about 500 locality-year observations. The data matrix is also quite sparse as most regional leaders serve in one to three localities for an average of 3-4 years.

I decided to use LASSO, which would grant me more degrees of freedom by throwing away the insignificant variables. Although I was told that AICc and cross-validation (and choosing the model that gives the minimum mean squared error) are theoretically equivalent, but in my dataset they perform very differently. LASSO gives much fewer non-zero individual coefficient estimates under AICc than under cross-validation (200 fold for a dataset wth 500 observations).

So my question is: Why do I see different results under AICc and cross-validation? And which criteria should I be using in selecting the model and reporting the results?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. And I'm happy to provide more details about my research if needed.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm answering here since I don't have enough rep to comment. If a moderator wants to move this to a comment, that'd be appreciated)

In short, AICc and cross-validation are theoretically *asymptotically* equivalent. That is, they will (eventually) give the right answer as $n \to \infty$. If you are in a situation where $p > n$ (and it sounds like you are), those asymptotics are very far off.

I'd probably use CV, but even better might be something like the "randomized lasso." [1]

Another thing to keep in mind: AICc and CV give *prediction* optimal tuning, which isn't necessarily the same as the best tuning for model selection. Model selection is much harder to tune for...

[1] S. Wang, B. Nan, S. Rosset, J. Zhu. "Random Lasso." Annals of Applied Statistics 5(1), p.468-485, 2011. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1300715199